# Unable to connect mysql database using valid details using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I've used the valid details to connect with mysql database and it was working fine. But, it raising the below mentioned error all of sudden. I've tried all possibilities to solve the issue. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
import mysql.connector.pooling

db_config = {
            'user' : 'root',
            'database' : 'persons_db',
            'host' : 'localhost',
            'password' : 'mypassword',
            'port' : 3306
        }

connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
    pool_name = "new_pool",
    pool_size = 10,
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
    **db_config)


print(connection_pool)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vy/IDMP_Flask/sample_db_conn.py", line 11, in <module>
    connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 179, in __init__
    self.add_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 290, in add_connection
    cnx = Connect(**self._cnx_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 272, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1052, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 246, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
TypeError: function takes at most 24 keyword arguments (25 given)
```

Comment: Can you provide the version of MySQL Connector/Python? Did you upgraded it recently?

Comment: @NunoMariz, i'm using mysql-connector-python : 8.0.29 version right now

Comment: This error means that the call of the connect() method of the C extension is giving more arguments than supported. This is probably due to the usage of an old C extension, meaning that you've installed (upgraded) to a version that didn't installed the C extension correctly. Try to uninstall the connector and install it again. After uninstall it check if /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/_mysql_connector.so exists, if yes delete it and then install the connector.

Comment: @NunoMariz Still I am getting same error.

Comment: @NunoMariz i've uninstall entire mysql-server and re-installed it. Now its working fine. It was some configuration error internallty, i think so..